# Retrofit asynchrone tash

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit

Here is my code:

```
    private void InitialContact(final Context context)
{
    final ContactDatabase db = new ContactDatabase(context);
    context.openOrCreateDatabase("****", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    if(refrech){
        refrech(db, context);
    } 
    getcontact(db, context);
    db.close();
}
```

A getContact fonction (In main thread)

```
   private void getcontact(final ContactDatabase db, final Context context){
    SQLiteDatabase dbread = db.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] retour = {
        "pseudo",
        "adresse",
        "image", "ID"
        };
    Cursor cursor = dbread.query("Contact", retour, null, null, null, null, "pseudo");
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String pseudo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pseudo"));
        Log.d("debug", "getcontact: "+pseudo);
        listcontact.add(new Contact(pseudo));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

And the Asynchrone task refresh

```
private void refrech(final ContactDatabase db, final Context context){
    final SQLiteDatabase dbwrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
    db.onRefresh(dbwrite);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
    int ID = preferences.getInt("ID", 0);
    if(ID != 0){
        ApiInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
        Call<ContactCall> mService = mApiService.getcontact(ID);
        mService.enqueue(new Callback<ContactCall>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactCall> call, Response<ContactCall> response) {
                ContactCall ContactCallobjet = response.body();
                ArrayList pseudo = ContactCallobjet.isLogin;
                for(int i = 0 ;pseudo.size() <= i; i++){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    String contact = (String) pseudo.get(i);
                    values.put("pseudo", contact);
                    values.put("adresse", "test");
                    values.put("image", "test");
                    values.put("ID", "5");
                    dbwrite.insert("Contact", null, values);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactCall> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "populateWithInitialContacts: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "populateWithInitialContacts: Error ID");
    }
}
```

My probleme is a getContact fonction is call before a asynchrone function (refrech)
I have test a CallBack but It did not work

Answer (score 0):

Have your `getContact` method be called in your onResponse and failure callbacks:

```
private void InitialContact(final Context context) {
    final ContactDatabase db = new ContactDatabase(context );
    context.openOrCreateDatabase("****", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    if(refrech){
        refrech(db, context);
    } else {
        getcontact(db, context);
    }
    db.close();
}

private void refrech(final ContactDatabase db, final Context context){
    final SQLiteDatabase dbwrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
    db.onRefresh(dbwrite);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
    int ID = preferences.getInt("ID", 0);
    if(ID != 0){
        ApiInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
        Call<ContactCall> mService = mApiService.getcontact(ID);
        mService.enqueue(new Callback<ContactCall>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactCall> call, Response<ContactCall> response) {
                ContactCall ContactCallobjet = response.body();
                ArrayList pseudo = ContactCallobjet.isLogin;
                for(int i = 0 ;pseudo.size() <= i; i++){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    String contact = (String) pseudo.get(i);
                    values.put("pseudo", contact);
                    values.put("adresse", "test");
                    values.put("image", "test");
                    values.put("ID", "5");
                    dbwrite.insert("Contact", null, values);
                    // call get contacts after the response
                    getcontact(db, context);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactCall> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "populateWithInitialContacts: "+t.getMessage());
                // call get contacts on error
                getcontact(db, context);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "populateWithInitialContacts: Error ID");
        // call get contacts on error id
        getcontact(db, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like another question to ask (also include the error logging stacktrace and information about the Contact tablet).  If you found that this answer solved your question accept it as an answer

Comment: In fact this is not an answer that works because asynchronous task.
My `private List<Contact> listcontact;` 
I fill in `listcontact.add(new Contact(pseudo));`   
Is clear at the end of the tash